# How to test Spring boot one to many JPA post request by curl o postman

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, postman

In my spring boot app I have the following models:-

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "STUDENT")
public class Student {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @Column
    private int mobile;

    public Student() {

    }

    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "DEPT_ID", nullable = false)
    private Department department;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getMobile() {
        return mobile;
    }

    public void setMobile(int mobile) {
        this.mobile = mobile;
    }

    public Department getDepartment() {
        return department;
    }

    public void setDepartment(Department department) {
        this.department = department;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", mobile=" + mobile +
                ", department=" + department +
                '}';
    }
}

    @Entity
@Table(name = "DEPARTMENT")
@JsonIdentityInfo(
        generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
        property = "id")
public class Department {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    public Department() {

    }

    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "department", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<>();

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<Student> getStudentList() {
        return studentList;
    }

    public void setStudentList(List<Student> studentList) {
        this.studentList = studentList;
    }
}


@RestController
public class StudentController {

    @Autowired
    StudentService studentService;

    @Autowired
    DepartmentService departmentService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/studentList", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody
    List<Student> getStudents(){
        return studentService.getStudents();
    }

    @PostMapping("/saveStudent/{deptName}")
    public String saveStudent(@RequestBody List<Student> studentList, @PathVariable String deptName){
        try {
            Department dept = departmentService.findDepartment(deptName.toUpperCase());

            for(Student student: studentList)
                student.setDepartment(dept);

            studentService.saveStudent(studentList);
            return "Student saved successfully..";
        }catch (Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return "Error in saving Student ..";
        }
    }
}
```

For the above app. I wanted to test it's post controller `localhost:8080 /saveStudent/hr`
Note that I save hr department already. I tired following JSON by Postman:-

```
{
"student": [{ "name": "masi",
"mobile": 12345,
"department": "hr"
}, { "name": "masi2",
"mobile": 1234500,
"department": "hr"
}]
}
```

I got the following error:-

> Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList<com.example.onetomany.model.Student>` out of START_OBJECT token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList<com.example.onetomany.model.Student>` out of START_OBJECT token
> at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]]

**Postman console log:-**

```
POST http://localhost:8080 /saveStudent/hr
400
183 ms
Network
Request Headers
Content-Type: application/json
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.26.1
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 57071c5d-e416-4b54-870a-9f318fee7166
Host: localhost:8080 
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 160
Request Body
Response Headers
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Wed, 15 Jul 2020 09:05:43 GMT
Connection: close
Response Body
{"timestamp":"2020-07-15T09:05:43.864+00:00","status":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":"","path":"/saveStudent/hr"}
```

I think my app is working correct. How can I make the correct JSON request by Postman or CURL?

Comment: can you please share your controller code, I want to see how you are using to accept the post body?

Comment: I had StudentController in my question. I wanted to test `@PostMapping("/saveStudent/{deptName}")
    public String saveStudent(@RequestBody List<Student> studentList, @PathVariable String deptName){` controller.  Also, I added the postman console log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should not add `student` in post body
Use like below

```
 [
  {
    "name": "masi",
    "mobile": 12345,
    "department": {
      "field":"value"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "masi2",
    "mobile": 1234500,
     "department": {
      "field":"value"
    }
  }
]
```

I donot know the field of department class please edit accordingly

Comment: When I tried this. I got this error:-  Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.lang.Long` from String "hr": not a valid Long value; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.lang.Long` from String "hr": not a valid Long value
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 5, column: 19] (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.example.onetomany.model.Student["department"])]

Comment: After that above error:- I tired this `[
  {
    "name": "masi",
    "mobile": 12345,
    "department": "1"
  },
  {
    "name": "masi2",
    "mobile": 1234500,
    "department": "1"
  }
]`

Comment: Then error: .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Unresolved forward references for: ; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.UnresolvedForwardReference: Unresolved forward references for: 
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 12, column: 1]Object id [1] (for `com.example.onetomany.model.Department`) at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 5, column: 22], Object id [1] (for `com.example.onetomany.model.Department`) at [Source: (PushbackInputStream);

Comment: department is an object the way i did for student you need to so the same for department.

Comment: I updated answer please check now and edit the field value in side department